# Elasticsearch index analyzer settings

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a beginner for elastic search. I tried to add an analyzer to my index. Here is the coding:

```
PUT drug_mono6/_settings
{
"analysis": {
"analyzer": {
  "attachment.content": {
    "type": "custom",
    "tokenizer": "Whitespace"
  }
}
}
}
```

However, I was not able to reopen the index after doing that. The error I received is:

```
{
"error": {
"root_cause": [
{
"type": "exception",
"reason": "Failed to verify index [drug_mono6/SMmaJ4iPTCSUHp-oedsadA]"
}
],
"type": "exception",
"reason": "Failed to verify index [drug_mono6/SMmaJ4iPTCSUHp-oedsadA]",
"caused_by": {
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "analyzer [attachment] must specify either an analyzer type, or 
 a tokenizer"
}
},
"status": 500
}`
```

Is there a way to modify the settings and remove the changes?

Comment: Try delete the index

Comment: There is no way you can delete an analyzer. The reason for the error must be using '.' in the analyzer name. Its considered as nested path divider in ES. Try using '_' instead.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
PUT drug_mono6
{
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "attachment": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "whitespace"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html